# APK files won't install

Tags: apk

I have a Samsung Note 3. For the last 2 months, I can download APK files - for example, just downloaded the new Google Play Store here: http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/10/09/breaking-google-play-store-update-5-0-31-adds-even-more-material-design-highlights-and-moves-whats-new-to-the-top-apk-download/ and it's on the phone, but when I open it and go to install it, when I touch INSTALL - nothing happens. It's there, but it won't install. This happens with any APK. one caveat: in the past if I've rebooted into safe mode - which of course means with no downloaded apps running - then and only then can I install. Some 3rd party app might be blocking me from installing. That's all the info I got. Can you help?

Comment: Do you have a "screen dimmer" app running?

Comment: I read that when I Googled it but not too my knowledge. I actually went through all my settings to find something

Comment: Can you tap the 'cancel' button? If you can cancel but not install, then there is some app that is displaying a screen overlay (such as a screen dimmer, as mentioned by @DanHulme). Android does this so a screen overlay can't make it look like the buttons are swapped or changed.

Comment: Lol yes! The cancel button works just fine! So now what?

Comment: More details on "secured buttons" are in the developer documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Security

Answer (score 3):

I had a blue light filter app running that dims the screen to prevent damage to your eyes, and it was apparently blocking the installation of APKs and the selection of certain menu options in other cases.